# How can I read a line of zeroes from a file with Python

Tags: python, file

I have a file with the following list of numbers:

```
892567
000000
7487
000 
2 
111111
```

When I use the readline method with Python3, every line filled with zeroes prints empty values...
How do I get those values to show as they are?
Here's my code:

```
f = open("sample.log","r")
for line in iter(f.readline,""):
    value = f.readline()
    print(value)
f.close()
```

Any help, will be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance

Comment: Is the data viewable if you open it in notepad? Sounds like it might be saved in a binary format if it's not printing zeroes.

Comment: It has nothing to do with the line being filled with zeroes, you are simply throwing away every other line (due to alternately calling `readline()` in two different places, and only using the return value from one).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
with open("sample.log") as f:
    for line in f:
        print(line)
```